# NSDictionnary : objectForKey return nil, even if the key is in the dictionnary

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having a strange problem while using NSDictionnary ...

I'm trying to retrieve an object for a key that is present is the dictionnary with the method objectForKey, but it returns nil instead.

When I print out the whole dictionnary, I can see clearly the key and the value I'm looking for.

Here is the code :

```
- (MObject *)GetWithMProperty:(MProperty *)prop {
    NSLog(@"We search an object for a property named %@", prop.Name);
    NSArray *keyArray =  [_dict allKeys];
    int count = [keyArray count];
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        MObject *tmp = [_dict objectForKey:[ keyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"Key = %@ | Object = %d", ((MProperty*)[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]).Name, tmp.GetTypeId);
        if (prop == [keyArray objectAtIndex:i])
            NSLog(@"Wouhou !");
        else
            NSLog(@"Too bad :(");
    }
    return [_dict objectForKey:prop];
}
```

And the stack trace :

```
2012-10-29 11:24:07.730 IOS6[1451:11303] We search an object for a property named Value
2012-10-29 11:24:07.730 IOS6[1451:11303] Key = Name | Object = 4
2012-10-29 11:24:07.731 IOS6[1451:11303] Too bad :(
2012-10-29 11:24:07.731 IOS6[1451:11303] Key = Value | Object = 0
2012-10-29 11:24:07.732 IOS6[1451:11303] Too bad :(
```

It's a bit complicated, I'm using J2ObjC to compile a fully functional Engine, and thus I can't modify the classes MProperty and MObject (used by the Engine).

MProperty doesn't conforms to NSCopying protocol, so I created a classe called IPhoneMProperty that inherits from MProperty and conforms to the protocol.

Here is this class :

```
@implementation IPhoneMProperty

- (id)initWithMProperty:(MProperty *)prop {
    self = [super initWithInt:prop.OwnerTypeId withNSString:prop.Name withInt:prop.TypeId withMBasicValue:prop.DefaultValue withInt:prop.Flags];
    return self;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    IPhoneMProperty *prop = [[IPhoneMProperty alloc] initWithMProperty:self];
    return prop;
}

@end
```

And the method I use to add object and keys to the dictionnary :

```
- (void)SetWithMProperty:(MProperty *)prop withMObject:(MObject *)obj {
    IPhoneMProperty *tempKey = [[IPhoneMProperty alloc] initWithMProperty:prop];
    [_dict setObject:obj forKey:tempKey];
}
```

I hope it's clear enough, actually it's the only solution I found for the moment, but it doesn't work :(

Can anyone helps me with this ?

Thanks !

Comment: PLEASE... Learn to use breakpoints so you can set them and then step through the code to check values of the objects you have. This will speed your development and debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists in the line

```
    if (prop == [keyArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

Instead, implement `isEquals:` method in your `MProperty` class.

```
-(BOOL)isEquals:(MProperty*)inProp {
  if( [inProp.name isEqualToString:self.name] )return YES;

  return NO;
}
```

And, here, instead of the line

```
    if (prop == [keyArray objectAtIndex:i])
```

use the following line,

```
    if ([prop isEquals [keyArray objectAtIndex:i]])
```

Comment: Did you get the problem and the solution? If not, please comment.

Comment: But actually that wasn't the big problem. The real problem is when calling the method ojectForKey, it returns nil because it can't find the object ... Do you have any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated your _dict object before using?

modify your code as follows & check.

```
- (void)SetWithMProperty:(MProperty *)prop withMObject:(MObject *)obj {
    IPhoneMProperty *tempKey = [[IPhoneMProperty alloc] initWithMProperty:prop];
    if(!_dict) 
        _dict = [[NSMutableDictionay alloc]init];
    [_dict setObject:obj forKey:tempKey];
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Yes, it is allocated, otherwise I would not be able to print what is in the dictionnary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the if condition to compare betweenstring values ? Like this :

```
if ([prop.Name isEqualToString:((MProperty*)[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]).Name])
            NSLog(@"Wouhou !");
        else
            NSLog(@"Too bad :(");
    }
```